Jacobian of elementwise multiplication $\mathbf{X}$ $=$ $\mathbf{A}$ $\odot$ $\mathbf{B}$
I have some matrix $\mathbf{X}$ $=$ $\mathbf{A}$ $\odot$ $\mathbf{B}$, where $\mathbf{X}$, $\mathbf{A}$, and $\mathbf{B}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$, and $\odot$ represents the elementwise multiplication operator -- the Hadamard product.
I know that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ can individually be written in terms of functions of some other matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{I \times J}$, and I am interested in obtaining the Jacobian of $\mathbf{X}$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{Y}$, i.e., I want to solve for $\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{Y})}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{MN \times IJ}$, using the Jacobians w.r.t. $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.
According to this stackexchange post discussing the Hadamard product,, user91684's answer implies that: The Hadamard product $\mathbf{A} \odot \mathbf{B}$ is bilinear and the derivative satisfies
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}(\mathbf{A} \odot \mathbf{B})=  \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A} \odot \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{A} \odot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{B} 
\end{align*}
Using this, I assume that the Jacobian looks something like this:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{Y})} = \frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A})} \frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{Y})} + \frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B})} \frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{Y})}
\end{align*}
and I believe that $\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A})}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{MN \times MN}$ and $\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B})}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{MN \times MN}$ are given as:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A})} = \text{diag} \bigg( \text{vec} \big( \mathbf{B}^\top \big) \bigg) \hspace{2.0cm} 
\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B})} = \text{diag} \bigg( \text{vec} \big( \mathbf{A} \big) \bigg)
\end{align*}
where $\text{diag} \big( \text{vec} ( \mathbf{A} ) \big)$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{MN \times MN}$ represents taking the vectorization of $\mathbf{A}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ and forming a diagonal matrix from its elements.
I don't know how to verify this. I am basing this off of similar derivations of Jacobians where we have normal matrix multiplication instead of elementwise matrix multiplication, but I don't know if similar rules apply for the Jacobian over elementwise multiplication.
I feel like this could be wrong. Noting that the Hadamard product is commutative, such that $\mathbf{A} \odot \mathbf{B}$ $=$ $\mathbf{B} \odot \mathbf{A}$, I feel like we can equivalently have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}(\mathbf{A} \odot \mathbf{B}) = \mathbf{B} \odot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A} \odot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{B} 
\end{align*}
where $\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A})}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{MN \times MN}$ and $\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B})}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{MN \times MN}$ could instead be given as:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A})} = \text{diag} \bigg( \text{vec} \big( \mathbf{B} \big) \bigg) \hspace{2.0cm} 
\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B})} = \text{diag} \bigg( \text{vec} \big( \mathbf{A} \big) \bigg)
\end{align*}
I don't know if things inside of here need to be transposed or not. This feels very wrong to me, and I was unable to find any resources about taking the Jacobian w.r.t. elementwise multiplication.

The things inside do not need to be transposed, your second formula is correct.

A sanity check that disproves your first approach: since $A \odot B = B \odot A$ as you noted, we should expect the formulas for
$$
\frac{\partial (A \odot B)}{\partial A}, \quad \frac{\partial (B \odot A)}{\partial A}
$$
to match, but the transpose in your first formula breaks this symmetry

I think the formula becomes a bit more obvious if you note that
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A \odot B) =
\text{diag}(\text{vec}(A)) \text{vec}(B) =
\text{diag}(\text{vec}(B)) \text{vec}(A).
$$

$
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm d}
\newcommand\m\mathbf
\newcommand\vecc{\mathrm{vec}}
\newcommand\diag{\mathrm{diag}}
$There is a straightforward way to turn
$$
  \dd(\m A\odot\m B) = \dd\m A\odot\m B + \m A\odot\dd\m B
\tag{$*$}
$$
into an expression for the Jacobian.
The differential is a linear transformation for fixed $\m Y$, and the Jacobian is its matrix (or rather tensor). For example, $\dd\m X$ takes in a small change $\delta\m Y$ to $\m Y$ and outputs the change $\dd\m X(\delta\m Y)$ induced in $\m X$. The equation ($*$) says that
$$
  \dd\m X(\delta\m Y) = \dd\m A(\delta\m Y)\odot\m B + \m A\odot\dd\m B(\delta\m Y).
$$
We need to write this as a matrix multiplication; given the way you've laid out your data, $\delta\m Y\in\mathbb R^{I\times J}$ and we use the vectorization operation $\vecc$ to write
$$
  \vecc[\dd\m X(\delta\m Y)] = \frac{\partial\vecc(\m X)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)}\vecc(\delta\m Y).
$$
We do similar with $\dd\m A$ and $\dd\m B$. Since the Hadamard product is elementwise, we can vectorize before applying it, yielding
$$
  \frac{\partial\vecc(\m X)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)}\vecc(\delta\m Y) = \left[\frac{\partial\vecc(\m A)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)}\vecc(\delta\m Y)\right]\odot\vecc(\m B) + \vecc(\m A)\odot\left[\frac{\partial\vecc(\m B)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)}\vecc(\delta\m Y)\right].
$$
The Hadamard product is commutative, and using the fact that e.g.
$$
  \vecc(\m A)\odot v = \diag(\vecc(\m A))v
$$
we get
$$
  \frac{\partial\vecc(\m X)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)}\vecc(\delta\m Y) = \left[\diag(\m B)\frac{\partial\vecc(\m A)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)} + \diag(\m A)\frac{\partial\vecc(\m B)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)}\right]\vecc(\delta\m Y)
$$
where I've abbreviated e.g. $\diag(\m A) := \diag(\vecc(\m A))$. It follows that
$$
  \frac{\partial\vecc(\m X)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)} = \diag(\m B)\frac{\partial\vecc(\m A)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)} + \diag(\m A)\frac{\partial\vecc(\m B)}{\partial\vecc(\m Y)}.
$$
